# Some operation like determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, integer-programming

we have determinant operation that is like below:

$
det(\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix})
$=
$
(-1)^{1+1}a(ei-fh)+ (-1)^{1+2}b(di-fg)+(-1)^{1+3}c(dh-eg)
$

Is there any other operation do like below?

$
Operation(\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix})
$=
$
a(ei+fh)+ b(di+fg)+c(dh+eg)
$

there is not $(-1)^{i+j}$ in it.

Comment: That missing factor is the sign of the permutation of the considered elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent), a not so friendly, but still useful concept.